# Need help with understanding this 3-way wiring setup

Tags: wiring

I have gone through multiple diagrams on the internet but not able to understand my dining room 3-way switch wiring setup. Any insight or next steps would be helpful.

What do I want to achieve?
I would like to install a 3-way smart dimmer switch that requires a neutral wire. Can I still do that by doing making some adjustments to existing wiring?

What I have?

- Light Fixture
- Switch Box 1
- Switch Box 2

Switch Box 1 has two wire bundles and a 3-way standard switch

- Wire bundle 1 has 2 wires - Black and White
- Wire bundle 2 has 3 wires - Black, Red and White
- White wire of Wire bundle 1 which seems hot connected to the Black wire of Wire Bundle 2 with a wire nut
- Black wire of Wire bundle 1 is connected to the Common screw of Switch 1
- Other two wires of Wire bundle 2 are connected to the Switch 1 (travelers)

Switch Box 2 has 1 wire bundle and a 3-way dimmer switch

- Wire bundle has 3 wires - Black, Red and White
- All three wires are connected to three parts of the 3-way dimmer switch

It goes without saying that there is a ground wire in both switch boxes.

What do I know so far?

- I think Power seems to be getting to the fixture first
- Do not see any neutral wire

What do I not know so far?

- Not sure why the white wire of Wire Bundle 1 in Switch Box 1 is hot?
- Not opened the fixture to see what is in there.

Thank you for your time.
Himanshu

Comment: Look (not very far) for the concept of a switch loop, and go LOOK in the light fixture junction box. You have a switch loop on a 3-way switch - but other than that, yup, it's a switch loop, power comes into the light and goes to and from the switch on a /2 wire

Comment: What make and model of smart dimmer do you want to install?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel thanks for your time. I would like to install Feit Electic Smart Wifi Dimmer switch.  Here is the link https://www.feit.com/product/smart-wi-fi-dimmer/

Answer (score 2):

Yup, you have a **switch loop** in a 3-way switch configuration.  The wiring is

Supply ------ Light -------- Switch1 ====== Switch 2

- The wires from Supply to Light are always-hot and neutral.
- The wires from Light to Switch1 are always-hot and switched-hot.
- The wires from Switch1 to Switch2 are always-hot and 2 travelers.

Your smart switch needs always-hot, switched-hot and neutral.  Those are not located at any switch location.

It won't be possible to install a smart switch in the normal way.  You'll need a smart switch module that sits in the lamp box and serves as the master, and smart-switch remotes at the physical switch locations.

Comment: Thank you for explaining with a diagram. Do you have a recommendation for a 3-way smart switch that can support this kind of configuration? I have checked multiple 3-way switches in my home and they all seemed to have a similar configuration. Thank you again!